# New to HashMap : how can I sort it?

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

So I have a HashMap looking like this :

```
HashMap<Movie, Float> movies;
```

It contains some movies with their global ratings as `floats`, and I want to sort the movies from the best to the worst.

I had a look in `Collections.sort()` but have no idea if I can do something with it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to sort a HashMap. If you need a sorted map take a look at [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

What about adding the rating value to the `Movie` class and let it implement `Comparable`?

```
public class Movie implements Comparable<Movie> {

    private Float rating;

    public Movie(Float rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public Float getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public int compareTo(Movie param) {
        return param.getRating().compareTo(rating);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(rating);
    }
}
```

Then you can use your `Movie` class like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Set<Movie> movies = new HashSet<Movie>();
    movies.add(new Movie(0.6f));
    movies.add(new Movie(0.5f));
    movies.add(new Movie(0.7f));
    movies.add(new Movie(0.2f));

    // Movie.class has to implement Comparable
    System.out.println("First option:");
    List<Movie> list = new ArrayList<Movie>(movies);
    Collections.sort(list);
    printMovies(list);

    // Works without implementing Comparable in Movie.class
    System.out.println("\nSecond option:");
    List<Movie> secondList = new ArrayList<Movie>(movies);
    Collections.sort(secondList, new Comparator<Movie>() {
        public int compare(Movie movie1, Movie movie2) {
            return movie2.getRating().compareTo(movie1.getRating());
        }
    });
    printMovies(secondList);

}

private static void printMovies(List<Movie> list) {
    for (Movie movie : list) {
        System.out.println(movie);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
First option:
0.7
0.6
0.5
0.2

Second option:
0.7
0.6
0.5
0.2
```

If you always want to sort the movies in the same way (from best to worse), I would choose the first option. If you always need different sort algorithms I would choose the second option, but even if your `Movie` class implements `Comparable` you can always provide a different `Comparator` as shown in the example.

Comment: While this is an ok solution, I think it makes the code easier to read if you use Comperator rather than Compareable in situations like this. When I read Collections.sort(list) I will often assume its sorted on title or similar, not on rating, but if I instead read Collections.sort(list, new Movie.RatingComperator()) I can see right away that it will be sorted by rating and not something else.

Answer (score 2):

HashMap is not the datastructure for what you want to achieve. you can read more about HashMap here for exmaple:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

what I suggest for you is to include your rating within your Movie object and make a Comperator that can compare your Movie objects based on rating. place the Movie's in a ArrayList, then you can sort it with the comperator and Collections.sort

Answer (score 2):

use [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html). From this [so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1283722/931982)

```
public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<String,Double> map = new HashMap<String,Double>();
        ValueComparator bvc =  new ValueComparator(map);
        TreeMap<String,Double> sorted_map = new TreeMap<String,Double>(bvc);

        map.put("A",99.5);
        map.put("B",67.4);
        map.put("C",67.4);
        map.put("D",67.3);

        System.out.println("unsorted map: "+map);

        sorted_map.putAll(map);

        System.out.println("results: "+sorted_map);
    }
}

class ValueComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    Map<String, Double> base;
    public ValueComparator(Map<String, Double> base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    // Note: this comparator imposes orderings that are inconsistent with equals.    
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        if (base.get(a) >= base.get(b)) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        } // returning 0 would merge keys
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Guava library](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) to do this - [there is already an excellent answer on here explaining how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3420912/98978).

Answer (score 2):

You could just use a TreeMap from the start. It is a sorted map, you just have to define a Comparator (in this case, use your floats)

If you want to stick to HashMaps, yes you can use Collections.sort. But again, you still have to learn how to use a Comparator.

Answer (score 1):

HashMaps are unsorted by default. If you need ordering either use a `TreeMap` or simply sort into a `List<Movie>`

```
List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<Movie>(); 
Collections.sort(movies, new Comparator<Movie>() {

        public int compare(Movie m1, Movie m2) {
            return m1.getRating() - m2.getRating();
        }
});
```